# How to call dispatch_block_t directly?

Tags: objective-c, macos, automatic-ref-counting, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to update [some code](https://github.com/OpenEmu/OpenEmu-SDK/blob/master/OpenEmuSystem/OESystemResponder.m#L185) for XCode 6.1 / Yosemite. It's a bit weird because it's a macro, but essentially it looks like:

```
dispatch_block_t blk = ^{ [[self globalEventsHandler] someMethod self]; };
if([NSThread isMainThread]) blk();
else dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), blk);
```

This is causing compilation problems. I have already set `OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0` per [GCD guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html) in my preprocessor settings, since right now I'm not interested in modernizing the code.

The first is `Implicit conversion of block pointer type 'void (^)(void)' to C pointer type 'dispatch_block_t' (aka 'void *') requires a bridged cast`. I can accept the suggest fix for this and get:

```
dispatch_block_t blk = (__bridge dispatch_block_t)^{ [[self globalEventsHandler] someMethod self]; };
if([NSThread isMainThread]) blk();
else dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), blk);
```

but now I get a new error: `Called object type 'dispatch_block_t' (aka 'void *') is not a function or function pointer`. And on that I'm stuck.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to call `dispatch_block_t` directly now? I have found the original code pattern in a few older blog posts, so I suspect it is (was) common.
2. Is `__bridge` the correct way to do this? There seem to be other options related to `dispatch_retain` and friends that may be appropriate.
3. I feel like I'm missing a fundamental concept here, which would be very likely since I'm quite inexperienced with OSX development.

For bonus points: how would you get this working without disabling `OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC`?

Comment: Your 1st snippet of code works fine for me fine on a new project, does it also give you problems in a new project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That code snippet is totally ok with Xcode 6.1 with OS X SDK 10.10. However, these compile error messages are odd.

```
Implicit conversion of block pointer type 'void (^)(void)' to C pointer type 'dispatch_block_t' (aka 'void *') requires a bridged cast

Called object type 'dispatch_block_t' (aka 'void *') is not a function or function pointer.
```

`dispatch_block_t` should be the following in `dispatch/object.h`.

```
typedef void (^dispatch_block_t)(void);
```

But these error messages say `dispatch_block_t` is the same as `void *`. Did you typedef `dispatch_block_t` yourself instead of including `Foundation/Foundation.h` or `dispatch/dispatch.h`? You'd better search `dispatch_block_t` typedef in your code.

Comment: aha, that's it! I was messing around with something completely unrelated a few weeks back and applied http://hamelot.co.uk/programming/osx-gcc-dispatch_block_t-has-not-been-declared-invalid-typedef/ but forgot to undo it.